# How do I build a memory dependency graph in LLVM?

Tags: c++, c, compiler-construction, llvm

Given some piece of LLVM bit code, I would like to build a graph of memory dependencies between instructions. I did find the [MemoryDependenceAnalysis](http://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1MemoryDependenceAnalysis.html#details) which seems to be the right start but the documentation is lacking so I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: The main functionality of this pass is within its `Result` (`MemoryDependenceResults`). You probably should use standard LLVM machinery to obtain pass analysis results (`PassManager::getAnalysis()`) to get access to that class.